# VSTS build error - MSB3327 Unable to find code signing certificate

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I try to setup our `WPF` applications build in Visual Studio Online (`VSTS`), but I got error:

*warning `MSB3327`: Unable to find code signing certificate in the current user's Windows certificate store. To correct this, either disable signing of the ClickOnce manifest or install the certificate into the certificate store.*

*Error `MSB3326`: Cannot import the following key file: . The key file may be password protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or import the certificate manually into the current user's personal certificate store.*

We use code signing on production, so I cannot disable this option or remove `<manifestkeyfile>` from `csproj`. IS there any way to import this certificate to `VSTS`? Couldn't find any info about this...

Actually, I only need to build it (without deploy) but it looks like I cannot turn of signing for particular configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message MSB3327 suggested, you can also **install the certificate into the certificate store**. Steps as below:

In your project properties window -> Signing Tab -> Select from Store -> certifacte properties -> Install Certificate -> select the options from certificate import wizrad until the import succeed.

[image]

Then commit and push the changes to VSTS repo and build again.